# Dúvida laço while

Tags: python-2.7, while

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def soma(lista):
    soma_num = 0
    while soma_num <= lista:
        soma_num += a
    return soma()
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(soma(a))
```

Eu sei que ele vai dar error na linha 7 e 10, dizendo não ser possível usar o operador += em lista e inteiro. Porém minha dúvida e a seguinte, neste código que montei só e possível resolver usando o laço for ou é possível utilizando o laço while.
Ou eu teria que adicionar um for dentro do while.
Pois eu tenho um exemplo e funciona perfeitamente com laço for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glaucio,

você consegue executar a sua função soma, tanto em um laço `while` quanto em um laço `for`.

```
def soma(lista):
    total = 0
    for item in lista:
        total += item
    return total

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print soma(a)
```

ou então:

```
def soma(lista):
    total = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(lista):
        total += lista[index]
        index += 1
    return total

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print soma(a)
```

ou como a função que você quer já está definida internamente no python, você pode simplesmente:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print sum(a)
```

Comment: Rubico essa minha dúvida mesmo, no laço for eu conseguia tranquilamente. Tava com problema no while mesmo.

Comment: ficou faltando um return ali, mas acho que deu para pegar a ideia. vou arrumar ;)

Comment: Deu pra pegar a idéia sim, valeu mesmo.